# MongoDB: What's the use of a secondary in a sharding scheme?

Tags: mongodb, google-compute-engine, sharding

I've read Google Cloud Platform's [article](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/deploy-mongodb) on deploying MongoDB. Using a sharding scheme, it is clear that the application will never read from a secondary MongoDB server:

> Because the production application never reads data from a secondary server, the application never needs to handle the complexity of stale reads and eventual consistency.

My questions are:

1. Are secondary servers only useful for fault tolerance, i.e. as a backup in case of a failure in the primary server? Or are there performance benefits to having secondaries within the same shard region?
2. If so, considering the following:

> Compute Engine disks have built-in redundancy to protect data against failures and to ensure data availability through maintenance events

Why are secondary servers needed at all on a fault-tolerant platform like Google Cloud?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the two questions:

**Other Benefits of Replica Sets**

Replica sets also allow you to [perform rolling updates to MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/your-ultimate-guide-to-rolling-upgrades) so are useful for supporting updates.

It is also possible to allow some applications (e.g. a reporting application) to read from a secondary which reduces some load on the primary.  Some details and use cases are available on the MongoDB site - https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/read-preference/

**Requirement for Secondary Servers**

The Google article states:

> Barring a catastrophic outage, the MongoDB primary server should
>   always be in this region

By having multiple members in a replica set you are protecting yourself from this kind catastrophic outage.  If you require very high availability then you want this level of protection.

MongoDB's own database as a service ([Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)) deploys replica set members to different Amazon Web Service Availbility Zones to protect against this kind of catastrophic outage.